# Empty error when reading 3D .wkt out put file of Mean Curvature sleleton

Tags: c++, geometry-generator, computational-geometry, cgal

I wrote a code that takes the 3D skeleton from the Mean Curvature Skeleton algorithm as an input to .wkt from the Polyhedron Demo program. It extends to the user with the radius it receives from the user.

[image]

But the error I get is: Error: No LineStrings Found in WKT File

[image]

I have put the data in this:
https://dpaste.org/8wJ5R
The code:
https://dpaste.org/TgMKU

I have changed the functions of Expand, Readwkt and ReadLineStrings and put a condition into their functions as well as main to know why the output file is empty then I get n = 0 and cannot read from the input file I have set my data. Wkt doesn't make sense?